# Why is my menu not dropping down with this CSS?

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu, hover

The `li` element with "portfolio" in the text is the element I would like to hover over to drop down. For some reason, nothing drops down when I hover over "Portfolio"...

Here is the code

```css
#navmenu ul {
  position: absolute;
  visibility: hidden;
  top: 30px;
}

#navmenu .hoverme:hover ul {
  visibility: visible;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">

  <div id="navmenu">
    <div class="hoverme"><a href="#">Portfolio</a>
      <ul>
          <li><a href="#">Reviews</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">Appendix</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">Team</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">Company</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">Individual</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">Cert of Att</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">Skills Prof</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">Csmr Visits</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">Income</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">Roles</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
     </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Do you know why? Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: Your HTML is invalid. You can't have a `<ul>` between `<ul>` tags, it must be within `<li>` tags. Perhaps this has something to do with your issues.

Comment: thank you for your reply. I am an absolute newbie, so forgive me for the pathetic mistakes!

Comment: Not pathetic at all! Sometimes you just need to ask the right questions!

Answer (score 1):

you need to close the `li` with *portfolio* after the child `ul`, otherwise your HTML markup is invalid, because you can't have `ul` as direct child of an `ul`

From [**Specs**](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/grouping-content.html#the-ul-element)

> **Content model:**
>
> Zero or more `li` and script-supporting elements.

```css
#navmenu ul ul {
  position: absolute;
  visibility: hidden;
  top: 30px;
}
#navmenu ul li:hover ul {
  visibility: visible;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="navmenu">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Portfolio</a>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">Reviews</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">Appendix</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">Team</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">Company</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">Individual</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">Cert of Att</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">Skills Prof</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">Csmr Visits</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">Income</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">Roles</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: thank you for your reply. I am an absolute newbie, so forgive me for the pathetic mistakes!